# IPTables Proxy NAT

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

I am trying to create a proxy NAT that will forward a port to a remote host. I have two interfaces: venet0:0 and venet0:18. I want to be able to forward connections from venet0:18 to venet0:0 and then out to a remote host.

I have tried this: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/595
and it does work but I cannot get it to forward the packets through my other interface (venet0:0).

Answer (score 0):

You're using OpenVZ, and doing NAT within an OpenVZ VPS container is tricky at best and often doesn't work right.

You can try asking your hosting provider to enable TUN/TAP support within your container.

If this fails to resolve the problem, you will probably have to use a different VPS based on different technology, such as KVM, VMware or Xen.

Comment: I have also tried to do it in VMware and it does not work.

Comment: I should rephrase that. It DOES work but what I am trying to do is make the traffic tunnel through a different interface.